# bundler cannot find a compatible version when I think it should

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I get this message from Bundler

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 5.1.7) was resolved to 5.1.7, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.1.7)

    simple_form was resolved to 5.0.3, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
```

Seems to me 5.1.7 should satisfy >=5.0 so actionpack 5.1.7 should be compatible.

What am I missing?

Comment: run `bundle update`

Comment: That's what I did that generated this message.